# How to call an async function during debugging?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I usually like to call some functions during debugging in the console just to see some quick results.
However with async functions, this doesn't seem to be possible:

```
import asyncio

async def func1():
    print('func1')

def func2():
    print('func2')

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    await task  # put a break point here

asyncio.run(main())
```

Let's say we put a break point in the line of `await task`
Now if I call `func2()` in the console it will print `'func2'` perfectly fine.
However, if I enter `await task` in console, I will get the below error:

```
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

python 3.9
pycharm 2022.3.1

Is there any way I can call the async functions in the console like the non-async functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend the `current_task` and then run the event loop until the `task` is done.

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import tasks

def wait(task_or_coro):
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(task_or_coro)
    loop, current_task = task.get_loop(), tasks.current_task()
    tasks._leave_task(loop, current_task)
    while not task.done():
        loop._run_once()
    tasks._enter_task(loop, current_task)
    return task.result()
```

Call `wait(task)` instead of `await task`.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious is this the 'canonical' way of debugging async functions?

Comment: It depends on the scenario; this seems to be the only way to do so from a debugger (it's generally not advisable to use single-underscore functions that are "private"). For the case in the question, I wonder why you don't simply Step Over/Into?

Comment: The reason that I cannot simply step into is that I often need to call those async functions out of order during debugging.